# How exactly do you do a Sonic Drift in the 3D daytime segments?

Tags: sonic-unleashed

Drifting in the daytime levels of Sonic Unleashed seems either really clumsy<sup>1</sup> or just plain hard. Even on the drifting course in Mazuri, it's astoundingly difficult to do it correctly (i.e. without falling off the track). I can't figure out if it's because I drift (press the shoulder button) too early, drift too late, turn too sharply or too little, or all of them combined.

At the risk of this being too broad a question, what tips, control-wise and timing-wise, should I keep in mind in order to pull off a successful and skillful Sonic Drift?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Apparently they refined the drifting controls for the modern Acts in Sonic Generations, as it's considerably easier to drift properly in Generations than in Unleashed. But your mileage may vary.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure if drifting is any different in the Wii/PS2 versions and the 360/PS3 versions of the same game either, hence the console tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to practice the timing of drifting, since Sonic controls like a Tank in Sonic Unleashed, hard to control or drift, unlike in Sonic Generations.

You might want to check this discussion thread. As there are discussions on how to properly drift or etc.

GameSpot thread: [How to Drift Video (getting the S Rank in Mizuri Act 2)](http://asia.gamespot.com/sonic-unleashed/forum/how-to-drift-video-getting-the-s-rank-in-mizuri-act-2-47287406/)

YouTube video:

The basic idea from this video is that you turn before you begin to drift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and welcome to Arqade! While we're totally okay with using links as citations for information, we usually also request that you quote at least the pertinent bits from what you're quoting, so that in case the link vanishes, we don't lose that info! Could you do so? You're always able to edit your own posts.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh Lol sorry! Just a newbie... I've edited it, not sure though if i did the right thing... Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: That'll do, yeah. :) And it's quite okay, that's why those of us that have been here for a while go around and check on newbie's first answers, so we make sure you're doing it right! ^^;

Comment: Hey Thony! Sorry I'd somehow missed your answer from several months ago. I've improved it further and marked it accepted. Thanks for your answer and welcome to the site!

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro No worries! Thank you very much. :)